# Formatting tikzpicture plots side by side/ how to use \begin{figure}[htdp] or \begin{figure}[h]

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, subcaption

I'm new latex. I've been trying to learn how to format these plots side by side on one line, but I have not been able to successfully. I don't understand how to use the \begin{figure}[h] feature or the subfigure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm, graphicx, pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Figure_1.png}, {logo.gif} }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}



\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
    \subfigure[Figure A]{\label{fig:a}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt]
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
            ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
            axis lines=center,
            axis on top=true,
            domain=-2.5:2.5,
            ylabel=$y$,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ]
        \\
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {0.5*(1 +tanh(\x))};
            \node [right, red] at (axis cs: -1.1,1.1) {$y = 0.5 *(1 + \tanh x)$};
            
            %% Add the asymptotes
            \draw [blue, dotted, thick] (axis cs:-2.5,0)-- (axis cs:2.5,0);
            \draw [blue, dotted, thick] (axis cs:-2.5,+1)-- (axis cs:2.5,+1);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    }
    \subfigure[Figure B]{\label{fig:b}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
          declare function={
            func(\x)= (\x <= 0) * (0)   +
                      and(\x > 0 , \x < 1) * (\x)     +
                      (\x >= 1) * (1)
           ;
          }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
            ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
            axis lines=center,
            axis on top=true,
            domain=-2.5:2.5,
            ylabel=$y$,
            xlabel=$x$,
        ]
        
        \addplot [blue,thick] {func(\x)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
   }
    \subfigure[Figure B]{\label{fig:c}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
          declare function={
            gunc(\x)= (\x <= 0) * (0)   +
                      (\x > 0) * (\x)     
           ;
          }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
            ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
            axis lines=center,
            axis on top=true,
            domain=-2.5:2.5,
            ylabel=$y$,
            xlabel=$x$,
        ]
        
        \addplot [cyan,thick] {gunc(\x)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \label{fig:image3}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `subfigure` environments inside a figure environment you need  to load up the `caption` and `subcaption` packages.

To be able to make them fit in one line they were scaled to 0.6.

**Note** You must clean your preamble. Many packages were loaded two or three times.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{caption} % added <<<<<<
\usepackage{subcaption}% added <<<<<<

\usepackage{showframe}%show margins <<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt, scale=0.6,]
                \begin{axis}[
                    xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
                    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
                    axis lines=center,
                    axis on top=true,
                    domain=-2.5:2.5,
                    ylabel=$y$,
                    xlabel=$x$,
                    ]
                    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {0.5*(1 +tanh(\x))};
                    \node [right, red] at (axis cs: -1.1,1.1) {$y = 0.5 *(1 + \tanh x)$};                   
                    %% Add the asymptotes
                    \draw [blue, dotted, thick] (axis cs:-2.5,0)-- (axis cs:2.5,0);
                    \draw [blue, dotted, thick] (axis cs:-2.5,+1)-- (axis cs:2.5,+1);
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{one}
            \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,
                declare function={
                    func(\x)= (\x <= 0) * (0)   +
                    and(\x > 0 , \x < 1) * (\x)     +
                    (\x >= 1) * (1)
                    ;           
                }
                ]
                \begin{axis}[
                    xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
                    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
                    axis lines=center,
                    axis on top=true,
                    domain=-2.5:2.5,
                    ylabel=$y$,
                    xlabel=$x$,
                    ]                   
                    \addplot [blue,thick] {func(\x)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{two}
             \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure} 
\hfill 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,
                declare function={
                    gunc(\x)= (\x <= 0) * (0)   +
                    (\x > 0) * (\x)     
                    ;
                }
                ]
                \begin{axis}[
                    xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
                    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
                    axis lines=center,
                    axis on top=true,
                    domain=-2.5:2.5,
                    ylabel=$y$,
                    xlabel=$x$,
                    ]                       
                    \addplot [cyan,thick] {gunc(\x)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{three}
             \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{Three graphs}
        \label{fig:image3}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you learn how to use this package?

Comment: @Robert Csete Google `latex subfigures` and you will find a good tutorial in `https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3):_Figures,_Subfigures_and_Tables` . (and many others). If everything fails, read the manuals. Perhaps you are lucky and they will have examples.

Comment: Uh, so ancient `pgfplots` version :-(. I believe that is time to upgrade (now is actual 1.18) :-)

Comment: @Zarko what's the new version I'm trying to use this code in a document and I keep getting an error:missing number treated as zero subfigure

Comment: @RobertCsete, `pgfplots` has nothing with `subcaption`. it only enables easier and better way to draw diagrams. Testing above answer with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` instead of `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}`, not produce any warnings nor errors.

Answer (score 0):

As supplement to @Simon Dispa answer, With use of recent version of the `pgfplots` package (if you not have installed, it is time now to do this), the code is a bit shorter.

Since all images have the same `axis` options, they can be merged to common settings for all diagrams in the `\pgfplotsset` inserted in figure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % <----

\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{
        xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
        ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
        axis lines=center,
        axis on top=true,
        domain=-2.5:2.5,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xlabel=$x$,
                }
    
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,]
    \begin{axis}
\addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {0.5*(1 +tanh(\x))};
\node [right, red] at (-1.1,1.1) {$y = 0.5 *(1 + \tanh x)$};
%% Add the asymptotes
\draw [blue, dotted, thick] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw [blue, dotted, thick] (-2.5,1) -- (2.5,1);
    \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{one}
    \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,
    declare function={func(\x)= (\x <=0) * (0)  +
                                and(\x >0, \x < 1) * (\x) +
                                (\x >=1) * (1);}
                            ]
    \begin{axis}
\addplot [blue,thick] {func(\x)};
    \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{two}
    \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,
    declare function={gunc(\x)= (\x <=0) * (0) +
                                (\x > 0) * (\x);}
                            ]
    \begin{axis}
\addplot [cyan,thick] {gunc(\x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{three}
\label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Three graphs}
\label{fig:image3}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)